# How to find the general term formula based on the relationship between the known sum and the general term?

Tags: differential-equations

The relationship between the known sum and the general term is as follows:

```
s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14
```

How to find the general term formula a [n]

```
RSolve[{s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14, a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1]}, 
 a[n], n]
```

RSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve `s[n]` at first. (we replace `a[n]` with `s[n] - s[n - 1]` and set `s[0]==0`)

```
sol = RSolve[{s[n] == (s[n] - s[n - 1])^2 + 1/2 (s[n] - s[n - 1]) - 
     14, s[0] == 0}, s, n]
```

```
a[n_] = s[n] - s[n - 1] /. sol[[1]] // Simplify
s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14 /. sol[[1]] // Simplify
```

> `1/2 (-8 + n)`.

```
a[n_] = s[n] - s[n - 1] /. sol[[2]] // Simplify
s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14 /. sol[[2]] // Simplify
```

> `(7 + n)/2`.

Comment: Does your answer contradict the result of `RSolve[{s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14, 
  a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1]}, {a[n], s[n]}, n]` which is `{}`?

Comment: You actually missed 2 solutions, please check my answer.

Comment: @yarchik: I prefer arguments over empty words. `s[n]==(7 + n)/2` implies `a[n]==1/2`, but think of `s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14`

Comment: @user64494 My comment was not directed to you.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality we can set $s(0)=0$ and search for a sequence $a(n)$, where $n\ge1$.
Using
$$
a(n)=s(n)-s(n-1),\quad n\ge1
$$

we obtain

```
RSolve[a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - (a[n - 1]^2 + 1/2 a[n - 1]) == a[n], a[n], n]
    (*{{a[n] -> (-1)^(-1 + n) C[1]}, {a[n] -> n/2 + C[1]}}*)
```

It remains to determine the constant `C[1]`.

**Case 1.**
$$a(n)=(-1)^{(n-1)} C[1].$$
Let us tabulate a few values of $n$ and find the constant that fulfills all equations

```
y[n_] := (-1)^(-1 + n) C[1]
Solve[Table[Sum[y[k], {k, n}] == -14 + 
   1/2 (-1)^(-1 + n) C[1] + (-1)^(-2 + 2 n) C[1]^2, {n, 5}]]
(*{{C[1] -> -(7/2)}, {C[1] -> 4}}*)
```

Thus
$$a_1(n)=-4(-1)^{n};\\
a_2(n)=\frac{7}{2}(-1)^{n}.
$$

**Case 2.**
$$
a(n)=\frac{n}{2}+C[1].
$$

Here we can proceed similarly

```
x[n_] := n/2 + C[1]
SolveAlways[Sum[x[k], {k, n}] == x[n]^2 + 1/2 x[n] - 14, n]
(*{{C[1] -> -4}, {C[1] -> 7/2}}*)
```

$$a_3(n)=\frac{n}{2}-4;\\
a_4(n)=\frac{n}{2}+\frac72.
$$

Thus, there are 4 solutions.

**Verification.**

```
a[1, n_] := -4 (-1)^n
a[2, n_] := 7/2 (-1)^n
a[3, n_] := n/2 + 7/2
a[4, n_] := n/2 - 4
Do[
 Print[AllTrue[
   Table[Sum[a[i, k], {k, n}] == a[i, n]^2 + a[i, n]/2 - 14, {n, 1, 13}], Identity]], {i, 4}]
(*
True
True
True
True
*)
```

Comment: Does your answer contradict the result of `RSolve[{s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14,    a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1]}, {a[n], s[n]}, n]` which is `{}`?

Comment: @user64494 Yes, looks like that.

Comment: Nice. It seems `RSolve` cannot handle a "difference-algebraic equation". Here's a way, perhaps not great: `raiseorder = {s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14, a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1]} /. {{n -> n}, {n -> n - 1}} // Flatten // Eliminate[#, Union@Cases[#, _[n - 2], Infinity]] &;
rsol0 = RSolve[Eliminate[raiseorder, {s[n], s[n - 1]}], {a[n]}, n];
Transpose@{rsol0, First@Solve[Eliminate[raiseorder, {a[n - 1], s[n - 1]}], s[n]] /. rsol0}`

Answer (score 0):

```
RSolve[{s[n] == a[n]^2 + 1/2 a[n] - 14,    a[n] == s[n] - s[n - 1]}, {a[n], s[n]},n]
```

> `{}`

No solution.